# How to increase the maximum connections number of a Serversocket?

Tags: java, serversocket

I want to test the limit connections of the ServerSocket.

This is my Server:

```java
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8088);
    ArrayList<Socket> connsList = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    while(true){
      connsList.add(server.accept());
      System.out.println(connsList.size());
    }
  }
}
```

this is my Client:

```java
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class Client{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    for(int i = 3000; i < 60000; i++){
      try{
        Socket con = new Socket("localhost", 8088);
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After run this code, when the connections increase, Server was shutdown when ArrayList's size is about 4000.

```
...
4031
4032
4033
4034
4035
4036
4037
4038
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Too many open files in system (Accept failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:551)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:519)
        at Server.main(Server.java:11)
```

It seems one server can only hold about 4k connections.

Is there some to increase this number?

Env

```
$ java --version
java 10 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

on macOS.

Comment: how many fd your os support？

Comment: @TongChen sorry, what is fd, please gives me more detail. I am macOS

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to to the java.net.ServerSocket but rather to your file system and how many file descriptors (FDs) can be open concurrently.

`$ ulimit -n`

Check this from a terminal. It is probably a number similar to 4000.

`$ ulimit -n <value>`

To change the amount.

Using this command does not change the ulimit permanently and exactly how to do that depends on what OS you run so I cannot give the exact solution.